# Angular2 rc.6 provide doesn't exist anymore

Tags: angular, typescript

I used to have an `ExceptionHandler` *(now `ErrorHandler`)* that I did provide to my module's providers :

```
import { provide } from "@angular/core"

@NgModule({
  providers: [
     provide(ExceptionHandler, {useClass: MyExceptionHandler})
  ]
})
```

I did rename `ExceptionHandler` to `ErrorHandler`. However, how should I deal with the provide *(since it doesn't exist anymore)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use an object `{ provide: ...}`:

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [
     { provide: ExceptionHandler, useClass: MyExceptionHandler}
  ]
})
```